# How to bypass pipe buffer size in Python / Windows

Tags: python, pipe, buffer

The binary data I am working with has about 80Kb and I need to write it to a pipe, then read it in another function. The problem is that the buffer size is limited to only 4096 Bytes, so it doesn't write (it freezes instead).

How to write and read using pipe these 80Kb of data?

```
file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'abc.png')
with open(file_path, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
    content = f.read()

content_length = len(bytearray(content))
print(f'content_length: {content_length}')

# if I enable the below, it's written and read
# -> only for limiting and testing the max size

# content = str(content)[: 4096] # max length / buffer (io) 4096
# content = content.encode('ascii')

r, w = os.pipe()
os.write(w, content)
print('Writing successfull')


def open_buffer(buffer, content_length):
    f = open(buffer, 'rb', buffering=0)
    content = f.read(content_length)
    #print(content)
    f.close()
    return content

open_buffer(r, content_length)
print('Success')
```

Comment: Why are you using a pipe to communicate between functions? Just use function arguments.

Comment: Pipes are for communicating between processes, and they shouldn't hang like this. The writing process will block until the reader reads the buffer, then continue automatically.

Comment: @Barmar because the actual function doesn't accept bytes. Instead it expects a file path in disk, which never exists and I don't want them to ever be written to disk (I would have many being created and deleted all the time).

Comment: So you're using a named pipe as the file? You need to run the writer and reader in different threads so you won't deadlock.

Comment: @Barmar Correct. I am just not sure if the other function can accept chunks of data (that one is a third party's), since it expects to read a file in disk. Will try it tomorrow.